# Equation Not balanced?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

I have this equation I am trying to solve and verify for a project, I am unabled to see what I'm doing wrong as I solve this equation. Been scratching my head for hours, I swear I did it right?
If you have interest on what these equations do, look here [3 Process Model](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0108679)
Please note, this is only the first equation located at the link(solve for ss).

Here is my work:

```
taw: 15
tas: 9
e: 2.718281828459
la: 2.4
ha: 14.3
g: -0.3813
d: -0.0353
PART 1: Solve For SW
Step 1 SW=ha-(ha-SS)*e^(g*tas)
Step 2 SW=14.3-(14.3-SS)*2.718281828459^(-0.3813*9)
Step 3 SW=14.3-(14.3-SS)*2.718281828459^(-3.4317)
Step 4 SW=14.3-(14.3-SS)*0.032331929746214
Step 5 SW=14.3-(0.46234659537086-0.032331929746214SS)
Step 6 SW=14.3-0.46234659537086-0.032331929746214SS
Step 7 SW=13.837653404629-0.032331929746214SS

PART2: Solve For SS
Step 1 SS=la+(SW-la)*e^(d*taw)
Step 2 SS=2.4+(13.837653404629-0.032331929746214SS-2.4)*2.718281828459^(-0.0353*15)
Step 3 SS=2.4+(13.837653404629-0.032331929746214SS-2.4)*2.718281828459^(-0.5295)
Step 4 SS=2.4+(13.837653404629-0.032331929746214SS-2.4)*0.58889934575108
Step 4 SS=2.4+(8.1489850367163-0.032331929746214SS-1.4133584298026)
Step 5 SS=9.1356266069137-0.032331929746214SS
Step 6 SS+0.032331929746214SS=9.1356266069137-0.032331929746214SS+0.032331929746214SS
Step 7 1.0323319297462SS=9.1356266069137
Step 8 1.0323319297462SS / 1.0323319297462=9.1356266069137 / 1.0323319297462
Step 9 SS=8.8495050319325

PART 3: Check SW Work
Step 1 SW=ha-(ha-SS)*e^(g*tas)
Step 2 SW=14.3-(14.3-8.8495050319325)*2.718281828459^(-0.3813*9)
Step 3 SW=14.3-(5.4504949680675)*2.718281828459^(-3.4317)
Step 4 SW=14.3-(5.4504949680675)*0.032331929746214
Step 5 SW=14.3-0.17622502038965
Step 6 SW=14.12377497961

PART 4: Check SS Work
Step 1 SS=la+(SW-la)*e^(d*taw)
Step 2 SS=2.4+(14.12377497961-2.4)*2.718281828459^(-0.0353*15)
Step 3 SS=2.4+(11.72377497961)*2.718281828459^(-0.0353*15)
Step 4 SS=2.4+(11.72377497961)*2.718281828459^(-0.5295)
Step 5 SS=2.4+(11.72377497961)*0.58889934575108
Step 6 SS=2.4+6.9041234152254
Step 7 SS=9.3041234152254  <---This value should be same as in PART 2
```

Comment: Reason for downvote would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell , you have two linear equations in the variables $SS$ and $SW$: 
$$ \eqalign{{\it SW}&={\it ha}-({\it ha}-{\it SS})\,{{\rm e}^{g\; {\it tas}}}\cr
{\it SS}&={\it la}+ \left( {\it SW}-{\it la} \right) {{\rm e}^{d\;{\it 
taw}}}}$$

The solution of these would be
$$ 
  {\it SS}={\frac {{{\rm e}^{d\;{\it taw}+g\;{\it tas}}}\it{ha}-
{{\rm e}^{d\;{\it taw}}}{\it ha}+{{\rm e}^{d\;{\it taw}}}{\it la}-{\it la}
}{{{\rm e}^{d\;{\it taw}+g\;{\it tas}}}-1}},{\it SW}={\frac {{
{\rm e}^{d\;{\it taw}+g\;{\it tas}}}{\it la}+{{\rm e}^{g\;{\it tas}}}{\it ha}-{
{\rm e}^{g\;{\it tas}}}{\it la}-{\it ha}}{{{\rm e}^{d\;{\it taw}+g\;{\it tas
}}}-1}} 
$$
You didn't tell us what $g$ and $d$ were, but you seem to be using $g=-0.3813$ and $d=-0.0353$.  Substituting in these and your values for
the other constants, you should get approximately
$$ SS = 9.312947477, SW = 14.13875897$$
which is not what you got.

Comment: This is helpful *and appreciated*, but I posted the steps I took to solve the equation, and I was hoping to see where I went wrong in my steps above?

Comment: Plug in my values of $SS$ and $SW$ into each of your equations, and see what is the first step where you get a difference (too big to be accounted for by rounding error) between the two sides.  That's where you made your first mistake.

Comment: Ah, it's step 6 of part 1.  You got a sign wrong.

Comment: So, 14.3-(0.46234659537086-0.032331929746214SS) simplifies to: 14.3-0.46234659537086+0.032331929746214SS ?

Comment: I apologize for leaving them out, I added g & d, and you are correct in their values.

Comment: thank you sir, you helped me find the error. :)